# Issue with the French Characters in Hibernate Query Comparision

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, encoding

I've a problem where there are comparisions with french characters. In already existing code uses a view that has 5 joins and uses a SQL function,  to convert french characters for comparision. Is there any way that I can minimize this.

My trails.

1. I have a name called 'ANDRÉ' that has to be given as input from a JSP page.
2. Then there comes the SQL function that converts the input accordingly from french to English. The function is written in such a way that it returns encoded string in lower case 'andre'.
3. Now with this result as criteria is searched for against the view that has 5 joins.

Is there any other way to encode or convert the string into lower case for comparision???

Please help out..

Comment: You can probably edit the collation rules on the database side. This would make 'a'='A'='à' etc.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I didn't get you. How to edit the collation rules???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
"from DataOrganization dataOrg where lower(dataOrg.poolName) like lower('%"+ poolName +"%')"
```

Comment: Where should this be specified?? Coz my code uses dynamically built HQL based on the criteria specified.

Comment: Just need to put lower against search column lists and against serach value, above is just an example for you to start with.

Comment: this might degrade performance as it will apply an analytic function on every line before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going the wrong way if you need to remove accented characters and lower case your strings for comparisons.  You should check the collation you are using in your database.  With french characters I would recommend `latin1` for MySQL and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` for SQL Server.

Basically [collation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) determines the way things are ordered and compared.  With the right collation "André" will be the same than "Andre" and even "ANDRE" without any messing with the input string.